# displaying comment author name in feed display not working

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have been displaying facebook page feed in a website well using graph api. 
I was also displaying those feed posts' comments with name and logo of who commented. 
But now i see error that there is no "name" field in comments node in graph api feed call when i use latest graph api version token. returned comments node look like this -

```
"comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "10155422440097217_10155422447452217",
            "message": "people dont learn  nationalism is rising again",
            "like_count": 4,
            "created_time": "2017-12-22T15:07:11+0000", ........
```

as seen above no name field returned per comment and no from field too. So clearly in latest graph api version that name and from fields removed. So i don't know how do i display author name of the comment, without author name people don't understand who commented(i can show their profile pic by user id but it's not enough). Any ideas about how i show comment author name when displaying FB page feed posts with comments per post? plz write with examples if possible.

Comment: thanks in advance who answers. I hope i wrote in details what i expected. i get all those posts data from graph api call and display in a website using php and javascript codes. Now the issue is comment author name is not returned in graph feed call

Comment: No one? it's a common error i think recently everyone getting while displaying FB page/group/profile posts in a website.

Comment: ok no idea? finally i found out i may have no alternatives other than using page access token because page access token returns from field in comment node?